# Change background colour of selected li item

Tags: html, css

I have made a nav with a list that gives a list item the class `.selected` when on the current page. I am trying to add a background colour to this class which works, but I can't get it to fill the whole `li` item. It's not adding any background colour to the left of the navs selected li item. Not sure if this makes sense?

Here's my html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's the css:

```
nav li {
  border-right: solid 1px #fbfbfb;
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 22px 15px 22px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  border-top: solid 1px #fbfbfb;
  border-left: solid 1px #fbfbfb;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #6e6e6e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2ecc71;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #2ecc71;

}
```

Comment: Can you put it up in a fiddle?

Comment: You have padding and margin in class nav li. Try to use padding and/or margin in .selected too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give some padding on the left to the `li` -

```
padding: 22px 15px 22px 15px;
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYH3Z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

change your  `padding-left` value:

```
nav li {
    padding: 22px 15px 22px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

margins and borders dont get background color.

try to cahnge it margin of li to either padding or a border of same size.

```
nav li {
  border-right: solid 1px #fbfbfb;
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 22px 15px 22px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list item with class `selected` *is* being completely filled according to the instructions you've given to the browser to display the `li` element with a `margin-left: 15px;` and `padding: 22px 15px 22px 0;`. The padding you have specified says there should be no padding to the left of the content in the list item (the last value of 0).

Try removing `margin-left: 15px;` and change your padding to `padding: 22px 15px 22px 15px;` for your `nav li` element, like so:

```
nav li {
  border-right: solid 1px #fbfbfb;
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 22px 15px 22px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
```